# A GUI library for j2me mobile app

Tags: user-interface, mobile, java-me, lwuit

I'm developing a simple j2me app. I'm using LWUIT library in order to create GUI for it. But it turns out that this lib is very slow on real phones (for example, when I press a button that redirects me to another form, it takes from 0.5 to 1 second for this form to load. I've tested it on my Nokia C5-03. In the emulator everything's fast.).

So now I'm searching for yet another, faster GUI lib for j2me. Please, can anyone give me a piece of advice of what lib is better to use? My requirements are:

1. There's some program for visual GUI development (like Resource
   Editor of LWUIT) coming with the lib.
2. I'll have a full control of the position of all the GUI elements on the screen
3. There's some efficient way to create and apply themes for my app
4. It should work comparatively quickly

Comment: I like too much this question. I think that LWUIT it's very slow in low cost mobiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is a version of lwuit customized for every nokia series 
when i developed for nokia s40 this issue solved when i used the s40 lwuit library
if you couldn't find the library for the nokia series you are developing for you can use canvas and draw your own GUI it's so fast

Comment: why not just use plain canvas? No need to import an almost 1MB library just to use canvas on it.